# App not destroyed while interacting with other apps?

Tags: android, button, back

Is it possible that my activity is not destroyed when i press the back key on my device?
It should have a button to do so. But i want it to continue running while i check my emails or something!

Comment: Depending on what your app is supposed to do you might want to use a [service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).

Comment: Pressing the "Back" key will always end the current activity. It is the same as calling Finish from code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible, but you're not supposed to rely on it.  Android simply leaves it in memory until it absolutely needs to be destroyed.  If you want something to run in the background until it's done, then you want to use a `Service`.

Comment: Alright here i need bit more help!I created an app that gets triggered by long press and gets the gps location on your device! Now, i want that application running a while, lets say when i go to home late at night. So i need this app not to allow the device to go to sleep and not to be "easily" destroyed! Do i need a service and how to use it?

Comment: Services are meant to run in the background without direct user interaction.  You're app can talk to it when you actually want to get information from it or you can use a notification to display the information you need.  Study this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html and this: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidServices/article.html